# Azure API query from Console return right answer, but from Curl - nothing

Tags: curl, azure-cognitive-services

I using Microsoft Bing Video Search API. Tested here: [Video Search API - V5](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f3ccf5ff8098cef3809/operations/56b440d2cf5ff8098cef380b/console).
Using simple request: `https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/videos/search?q=versace&count=105&offset=0&safeSearch=Strict&freshness=Day`.
Result from Console has many posts. But when I try use same request by curl, it return this result:

```
{
    "_type": "Videos",
    "instrumentation": {
        "pageLoadPingUrl": "https://www.bingapis.com/api/ping/pageload?IG=3A7948EA98004565BA8792996C75073B&CID=38B87B1BA5B4653B13C371E1A41264EA&Type=Event.CPT&DATA=0"
    },
    "value": [] }
```

I found, that if I remove parameter `freshness`, result will give more posts. I need this parameter, so case 'remove it' does not fit.
Please, help me:
 - how to use or modify the request?
 - why this request right work from Console, but not work by curl?
Thanks

Comment: Did you make sure to quote and/or escape the URL?  The precise command line and environment will be helpful to know.

Comment: @cthrash I wrote exactly that string, that used for curl like url parameter. What you mean about escaping?.. Is there I need to escape something in this string?

Comment: I assumed when you said 'used curl', you meant 'used curl in the command line.'  Is that correct?  Or are you using libcurl?  It would be helpful if you could be more precise.

Comment: I using php-curl. But using command line it return right response.
Trying to use simple call:
`<?php
$key = '';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/videos/search?q=versace&count=105&offset=0&safeSearch=Strict&freshness=Day');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {$key}"]);
?>`
So, what can be wrong?..

Comment: @cthrash Yes, you was right! Thanks! It should be wrap by htmlentities(). After that it return items

Comment: @cthrash It was wrong solution... After wrapping by htmlentities() query was return result without filters (freshness, safeSearch etc), that's why it return something... So, issue still exist.

Comment: When trying this one request:
`$ curl -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxx" "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/videos/search?q=versace&safesearch=Strict&freshness=Day&count=105&offset=0"` It return empty response: `{"_type": "Videos", "instrumentation": {"pageLoadPingUrl": "https:\/\/www.bingapis.com\/api\/ping\/pageload?IG=3CAE2A0BF84443A99B332752AACDBD05&CID=38A15BB0F5AD6E162394514CF4AB6F7E&Type=Event.CPT&DATA=0"}, "value": []}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found possible cause. If I add `'cc' => 'US'` or `'mkt' => 'en-US'`, it return the results... It's really strange, because official documentation not tell about that request have default value. That's why with same requests from different countries will get different results.
I'm really sad, that so many time I spent to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'q' => 'versace',
    'count' => 105,
    'offset' => 0,
    'safeSearch' => 'Strict',
    'freshness' => 'Day');

$ch = curl_init("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/videos/search?" . http_build_query($args));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: YOUR_API_KEY'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump(json_decode($json));
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Result is the same that I wrote in the top: array 'value' is empty.

Comment: That's really strange - that was code I tried verbatim (excepting the API key) and it game me dozens of responses, the top one being [this](https://www.bing.com/cr?IG=551735AB3C654D729C07B301B09EC805&CID=09381D1AD8D06B31036117E7D9D66A1F&rd=1&h=E23u73MynKRD0FzlTlia14wVLXUR7TenxYcMb8jfDO8&v=1&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fvideos%2fsearch%3fq%3dversace%26view%3ddetail%26mid%3d71F971415B97042CE90571F971415B97042CE905&p=DevEx,5408.1).  The symptom sounds very much like the query term being something bogus.  You really should just share your code snippet.

Comment: I'm copied exactly your code. Only change was YOUR_API_KEY. I tried both of them. And get in both cases empty 'value'.